# Autolayout subview alignment

Tags: ios, constraints, autolayout

I'm trying to make buttons on view. The problem is: this view will be resized (for example, after device rotation). 
So I have this: 
[image]

It's OK, but when I rotate the device, it looks like this:
[image]

I want it was like at the first screen, but with wider spacing between buttons.
So I've tried to make constraints like this: [image]

With priority 200 for --- selected constraints. But it still does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing the Relation from **Equal** to **Greater than**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by adding spacer elements between them. The size of the spacers can grow, while the size of the buttons can stay the same.

See this for an example: [Can AutoLayout equally space multiple buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299584/can-autolayout-equally-space-multiple-buttons)

Comment: Glad to have helped, @Maria :-)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it done to look like this:

[image]

To do this, you need to change the way you're thinking about it. I assume you were thinking "I want each button to have width of 70 and the spacing between the buttons to grow and shrink". But instead, you need to think "I want 4 buttons of equal sizes, with 50 pixels between their frame, so the frame of the button is growing/shrinking instead of the spacing".

With that, you select all 4 buttons and add an "Equal width" constraint.

Then you add 5 constraints for the spacing (Leading Space - Horizontal Spacing x3 - Trailing space) of Relation "Equal".

Comment: interesting idea, but I have background image for all of the buttons, and if it's frame change, that images will stretch.